# Protobuf de-serializing exception "A repeated type was not expected as an aux type"

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

When trying to deserialize an observablecollection, it gives me an exception
**"

"**An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in protobuf-net.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: A repeated type was not expected as an aux type:**""**

```cs
  public Task<T> ReceiveDataAsync<T>(TcpClient client)            
        {
            using (NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client.Client, false))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<T>(stream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32));
            }
        }
```

I haven't found details about this exception at all.

Answer (score 3):

The WithLengthPrefix API expects a single message, not a collection. Maybe serialize something that *has* a collection.

Comment: Hello Marc, serializing the collection seems to be fine, but de-serializing is not fine?

Comment: @Jackou well, the fact that it is failing tells me I don't have tests for this usage, so: I can't immediately tell you what the payload is. It can probably be changed to work, but: I'd need to investigate.

Comment: I see. I'll try to think of an efficient solution for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: it works fine with MemoryStream, I tried serializing a collection and deserializing and it didn't have a problem. I have no idea what the exception could mean.

Comment: @Jackou that's odd - especially it working differently on different stream types; I'd need to investigate; unfortunately, this isn't my day job, so it needs to wait on my availability

Comment: All good, I'll try to mess around with it to see the problem. Thanks for the time